# Disable column of Value Table in Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-toolbox, value-table

Can I disable a column based on another column?

Let's say I have a column to choose a field type (Short, String and so on) and a second column to choose the max length of a string. I would like to disable the second column if I've chosen a short instead of a string.

```
param = arcpy.Parameter("fields", "Param", "Input", "Value Table")
param.columns = [['String', 'Field Type'], ["Long", "String Length"]]
```

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can enable/disable a column in a ValueTable as there is no `enable` property for a column.

You may be able to remove a column but that would be weird behaviour for the end user.

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting an answer like yours. :-) However, speaking about weird behaviour... ArcGIS is full of it. I've never seen such a bad usability. No worries, I won't do that in my tool. ;-)